# Linked List: Sublime text crashing when printing the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list

```
class Node:
def __init__(self,data):
    self.data=data
    self.next=None

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head=None
    def printList(self):
        temp=self.head
        while(temp):
            print(int(self.head.data))
            temp=self.head.next
    def insertEnd(self,data):
        newnode=Node(data)

        if self.head is None:
            
            self.head=newnode
        else:
            last=self.head
            while(last.next):
                last=last.next
            
            last.next=newnode

    def delEnd(self):
        if self.head is None:
            print("Empty")
        else:
            last=self.head
            while(last.next):
                last=last.next
            print(last.data)
            del last
lst=LinkedList()
while(1):
    choice=int(input("1:To Insert at end \n2:To delete at end \n3:To print list"))
    if choice==1:
        value=int(input("Enter the value: "))
        lst.insertEnd(value)
    elif choice==2:
        lst.delEnd()
    elif choice==3:
        lst.printList()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your loop in `printList`, you're not using `temp` when you should:

```
    while(temp):
        print(int(self.head.data))
        temp=self.head.next
```

If the list has more than two nodes, this loop runs forever, since `temp` always gets set to `self.head.next` over and over.

You want:

```
    while temp:
        print(int(temp.data))
        temp = temp.next
```

Comment: is the function used to del the node at the end is correct? It is not doing anything.

Comment: That should probably be its own question. It doesn't work because `del last` only removes the `last` local variable from your function, it doesn't change the linked list structure at all. You probably want your loop to be `while last.next.next` and then to set `last.next` to `None` when the condition fails. You need to be modifying the *next to last* node, which is going to become the last one, after you unlink the last node from the list.